# How to get rid of libthread_db

Tags: linux, embedded, pthreads

On an embedded file system, I would like to get rid of libthread_db. My understanding
was that it was only necessary when debugging a program using pthread. However, here is my observation :

- If the libthread_db is not present at boot time (when the first pthread using programm is launched), launching such a program causes a segfault.
- Adding libthread_db later (ie after a pthread program has segfaulted) doesn't change anything. Every program that uses pthread will segfault on launch.

So it seems libthread_db is essential to run any sort of program using pthread.

Comment: Using `ldd`, I can't locate a threaded program that links against libthread_db. What C library are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`libthread_db` is *never* used by a threaded program. It is *only* used by the debugger.

Your assertion that `libthread_db` is somehow required to run a program using pthreads is incorrect. If your pthread programs crash when `libthread_db` is removed from the system, something *else* is broken on your embedded target; removal of `libthread_db` merely triggers that something else.

You can trivially confirm this: build a pthread program on a regular Linux system. Run that program under `strace`, and observe that `libthread_db` does not appear in `strace` output. Now rename `/lib/libthread_db.so.1` to something else, and observe that the test program continues to work just fine.

Comment: +1, He's got something else going on, probably with how the thread lib was compiled.

Comment: Thanks to confirm that libthread_db should not be necessary. I will make further tests

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `target record`

http://sources.redhat.com/ml/gdb/2010-07/msg00096.html